# Will a person die if his old name or new name is written in death note?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-note

In today's world there are several people who change their names. So would writing either their new or old name in death note kill them? When looked through shinigami eyes which name would you see?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [wikia's description](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) of the rules of Death note:

> This note will not take effect unless the **writer has the person's face in their mind when writing his/her name.** Therefore, people sharing the same name will not be affected.

So even if the person's name is changed or not, the writer thinks of the person's face while writing and thus there is no confusion regarding old/new names. The guy/gal is just dead...

Comment: While this is true, it needs both Name AND picturing the person's face. The question is whether it would work while picturing the person and the OLD name or picturing the person and the NEW name.